# Setting up Google ReCaptcha in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to get the callback to work in regards to Google ReCaptcha but I cannot figure out how to do so properly.

The form is handled both client-side and server-side validation and the rest of the fields are properly validating but I cannot get the Google ReCaptcha to validate properly and have the data sent to the server for a response and then processed.

What I read is that I need to add something like:

```
data: { 'g-recaptcha-response' : grecaptcha.getResponse()};
```

But I am not sure exactly. Can someone help me out?

**ajax.php:**

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$response = [
    'status' => 'success',
    'message' => 'Mail sent successfully',
    'data' => []
];



//Checking is it ajax request
if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest') {
    //Invalid Ajax request
    http_response_code(403);
    $response = [
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Invalid request, please try again.',
        'data' => []
    ];
    responseHandler($response);
}

if( !isset($_POST['data']) ) {
    http_response_code(400);
    $response = [
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Empty post data.',
        'data' => []
    ];
    responseHandler($response);
}
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true); $errors = '';

//Email validation
if ( isset($data["emailAddress"]) && !empty( $data["emailAddress"] ) ) {
    $email = trim($data["emailAddress"]);
    if ( filter_var($emailAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
        $errors .= "$emailAddress is <strong>NOT</strong> a valid email address.<br/>";
    }
} else {
    $errors .= 'Please enter your email address.<br/>';
}
//First Name Validation
if ( isset($data["firstName"]) && !empty( $data["firstName"] ) ) {
    $name = trim( $data["firstName"] );
    if ( filter_var($firstName, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === false){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a valid first name.<br/>';
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstName)) {
        $errors .= 'Only letters and white space allowed for first name...<br/>';
    }
} else {
    $errors .= 'Please enter your name.<br/>';
}

//Last Name Validation
if ( isset($data["lastName"]) && !empty( $data["lastName"] ) ) {
    $name = trim( $data["lastName"] );
    if ( filter_var($lastName, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === false){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a valid name.<br/>';
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastName)) {
        $errors .= 'Only letters and white space allowed for last name...<br/>';
    }
} else {
    $errors .= 'Please enter your name.<br/>';
}

//Company Name Validation
if ( isset($data["companyName"]) && !empty( $data["companyName"] ) ) {
    $name = trim( $data["companyName"] );
    if ( filter_var($companyName, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === false){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a valid name.<br/>';
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$companyName)) {
        $errors .= 'Only letters and white space allowed for company name...<br/>';
    }
} else {
    $errors .= 'Please enter your name.<br/>';
}

//Company Address Validation
if ( isset($data["companyAddress"]) && !empty( $data["companyAddress"] ) ) {
    $subject = trim( $data["companyAddress"] );
    if ( filter_var($companyAddress, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === false){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a company Address to send.<br/>';
    }
} else {
    $errors .= 'Please enter a company Address to send.<br/>';
}

//City Name Validation
if ( isset($data["city"]) && !empty( $data["city"] ) ) {
    $name = trim( $data["city"] );
    if ( filter_var($city, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === false){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a valid city.<br/>';
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city)) {
        $errors .= 'Only letters and white space allowed for city name...<br/>';
    }
} else {
    $errors .= 'Please enter your city name.<br/>';
}


//Message Validation
if ( isset($data["message"]) && !empty( $data["message"] ) ) {
    $message = trim( $data["message"] );
    if ( filter_var($message, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === false){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a message to send.<br/>';
    }
} else {
    $errors .= 'Please enter a message to send.<br/>';
}

//Start of ReCaptcha
$response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $data = array(
        'secret' => 'secret_password',
        'response' => $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
    $options = array(
        'http' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $captcha_success=json_decode($verify);
    if ($response["success"] = false) {
        $errors .= 'ReCapatcha is required.<br/>';
} else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {

if(!empty( $errors )) {
    http_response_code(400);
    $response = [
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => $errors,
        'data' => []
    ];
    responseHandler($response);
}
}
//End of ReCaptcha

//Filtering out newlines in the email subject
$subject = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$subject);
$contactContent = file_get_contents('email_templates/contact.html');;
$parameters = ['name' => $name, 'to_name' => TO_NAME, 'message' => $message ];

if(! send_mail( $email, $subject, $contactContent, $parameters ) ){
    //Email sent failed.
    http_response_code(500);
    $response = [
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Email service failing temporarily Or Maybe you are entered invalid E-mail, Please enter valid email and try again.',
        'data' => []
    ];
    responseHandler($response);
} else {
    //Email successfully sent
    http_response_code(200);
    responseHandler($response);
}

/**
 * responseHandler function
 * @param array $response request response
 */
function responseHandler($response)
{
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}

/**
 * send_mail function
 * @param  string $email             [[Description]]
 * @param  string $Subject           [[Description]]
 * @param  string $message           [[Description]]
 * @param  array [$parameters = []] [[Description]]
 * @return boolean  [[Description]]
 */

function send_mail($email, $Subject, $message, $parameters = []){
    ////Parse the message with given parameters
    if( !empty( $parameters ) )$message = parse($message, $parameters);



    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = SMTP_HOST;  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = SMTP_AUTH;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = SMTP_USERNAME;
    $mail->Password = SMTP_PASSWORD;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = SMTP_SECURE;                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = SMTP_PORT;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    if( isset($parameters['name']) )
        $mail->setFrom($email, $parameters['name']);
    else
        $mail->setFrom($email);


    $mail->addAddress(TO_EMAIL);     // Add a recipient
    //$mail->addReplyTo($email, 'Smart Invoice V3 Promotion');
    $mail->addBCC(TO_EMAIL);

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $Subject;

    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($message);

    if(!$mail->send()) {//$mail->ErrorInfo;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


/**
 * parse function
 * @param  string $message    [[Description]]
 * @param  array $parameters [[Description]]
 * @return string [[Description]]
 */
function parse($message, $parameters) {
    foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
        $message = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $message);
    }
    return $message;
}
```

**script.js:**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#loader").fadeOut("slow");
    $('#main').fadeIn("slow");
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            element.removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error'),
        }
    });
    $('#contactForm').validate( {
        submitHandler : function(form) {
            return false;
        },

        rules : {
            emailAddress:{
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            firstName:{
                required : true,
                minlength : 3,
                maxlength : 50
            },
      lastName:{
        required : true,
        minlength : 3,
        maxlength : 50
      },
      companyName:{
        required : true,
        minlength : 3,
        maxlength : 50
      },
            companyAddress: {
                required : true,
                minlength : 10
            },
            city: {
                required : true,
        minlength : 10
            },
            message: {
                required : true,
                minlength : 50
            }
        },
        messages : {
            emailAddress:{
                required : "Please enter your Email"
            },
            firstName:{
                required : "Please enter your name"
            },
      lastName:{
        required : "Please enter your name"
      },
      companyName:{
        required : "Please enter your name"
      },
            companyAddress: {
                required : "Please enter your contact purpose",
                minlength : "Minimum length of subject must be 10 chars long."
            },
            city: {
                required : "Please enter your contact purpose",
        minlength : "Minimum length of subject must be 10 chars long."
            },
            message: {
                required : "Please enter your sweet message",
                minlength : "Minimum length of your message must be 50 chars long."
            }
        },
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            $(element).closest('div.form-group').find('.help-block').html(error.html());
        },
        highlight : function(element) {
            $(element).closest('div.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
             $(element).closest('div.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
             $(element).closest('div.form-group').find('.help-block').html('');
        }
    });



    $(document).on('click', '#sendMailBtn', function(e){



        e.preventDefault();
        if( $('#contactForm').valid() ) {
            var sendMailBtn = $('#sendMailBtn');
            sendMailBtn.button('loading');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data : { data: JSON.stringify($('#contactForm').serializeObject()) },
                success: function( response ){
                    sendMailBtn.button('reset');
                    $('input,textarea').val('');
                    showSuccessMessage();
                },
                error: function( response ) {
                    sendMailBtn.button('reset');
                    if( response.status === 400 || response.status === 403 || response.status === 500 ) {
                        showWarningMessage(response.responseJSON.message);
                    } else {
                        showWarningMessage();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });

    function showSuccessMessage(){
        swal({
            title: "Many Thanks!!!",
            text: "Thanks for contacting us, We will get back to your inbox shortly...",
            type: "success",
            html: true
            /*imageUrl: "img/thumbs-up.jpg"*/
        });
    }

    function showWarningMessage(message){
        if(typeof message === 'undefined' || message === '' ) message = "Something went wrong, Please try again.";
        swal({
            title: "Oops...",
            text: message,
            type: "error",
            html: true
        });
    }

    $.fn.serializeObject = function()
    {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
});
```